# Drupal 8. Comments field on edit node page

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-comments

Why comments field is not displayed on node edit form? Is it even possible to display comments field on edit form?

Comments field is added to content type and is showing only in node display mode.

Comment: Humm did you check your display settings ?

Comment: Yes, comment and reply form are shown on node/123 page, but not on node/123/edit page.

I wonder, if there a way to add comments field to edit page.

Answer (score 1):

Comment field purpose is not for the site manager. it is for the site visitors. This is the reason why it is not editable in the node edit form.

Comment: To expand on HagitB's clarification, if you are looking to have internal comments for editors, you may want to utilize the built-in "revision" tracking.